# ChartJS - Returning labels and data from server on different calls

Tags: javascript, oop, chart.js

I am using classes to build charts and the thing with this one is: I need to return from the server dynamic labels and data every often. With this code I have accomplished to print on the console results I want for each function separately - array of `carNames` and array of `avgSpeeds`, but drawing the chart itself by the function `drawSpeedChart` has been really painful. Could anyone give me a way to pursue in order to get these printed results to render the chart? Thanks!!!

Here is the function that would supposedly render the chart:

```
drawSpeedChart() {
    this.labels;
    this.avgData;
    this.getAvgData()
        .then(avgData => {
            this.avgData = avgData
            console.log(this.avgData)                
            this.getCarNames()
        }).then(carNames => {
            this.carNames = carNames
            console.log(this.labels)                
        }).then(this.createChart(this.labels, this.avgData))
}
```

Both `console.log()`return `undefined` for this snippet.

Main functions to return `labels` and `data` are respectively `getCarNames` and `getAvgData`and they at least print in console the right result. Problem is to build the chart after that

Here is the full code.

```
window.onload = () => { new AvgSpeedChart(); }

class AvgSpeedChart {

constructor() {
    this.selectElements()
    this.drawSpeedChart()
}

selectElements() {
    this.speedChartElement = document.querySelector('#speedChart')
}

createChart(carNames, avgData) {
    return new Chart(this.speedChartElement, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: carNames,
            datasets: [{
                label: "Velocidade média",
                data: avgData
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Velocidade média'
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }         
    })
}

drawSpeedChart() {
    this.labels;
    this.avgData;
    this.getAvgData()
        .then(avgData => {
            console.log(this.avgData)                
            this.getCarNames()
            return this.avgData = avgData
        }).then(carNames => {
            console.log(this.labels)
            return this.labels = carNames                
        }).then(this.createChart(this.labels, this.avgData))
}


getCarNames() {
    return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        auth: {
            username: 'xxxxx',
            password: 'xxxxx'
        }
    }).then(response => {
        this.carNames = response.data.map(car => car.name)
        console.log(this.carNames)
        return this.carNames
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}

getAvgData() {
    return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: "xxxxxx",
        auth: {
            username: 'xxxxx',
            password: 'xxxxx'
        }
    }).then(response => {
        this.devicesId = response.data.map(device => device.id)
        return this.devicesId          
    }).then(devicesId => {
        this.getAllSpeed(devicesId.map(e => this.getAvgSpeed(e)))
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}

getAllSpeed(arr) {
    return axios.all(arr)
        .then((avgSpeeds) => {
            console.log(avgSpeeds)
            return avgSpeeds
        })
}

getAvgSpeed(deviceId) {
    return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: "xxxxxxx",
        auth: {
            username: 'xxxxx',
            password: 'xxxxx'
        },
        params: {
            from: '2018-10-09T00:00:00',
            to: '2018-10-09T23:59:59',
            deviceId: `${deviceId}`
        }
    }).then(response => {
        this.allSpeeds = response.data.map(pos => pos.speed)
        let sumSpeed = this.allSpeeds.reduce(this.sumSpeeds, 0)
        let numSpeed = this.allSpeeds.length === 0 ? 1 : this.allSpeeds.length 
        let avgCalc = ((sumSpeed/numSpeed)*1.852)
        return avgCalc
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}

sumSpeeds(total, sum) {
    return total + sum
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `drawSpeedChart` method is that the properties which you are using with `this` does not exist on your class. I've made them local variables. And you don't need the third `then` because you already have all the information to call `createChart` method.

```
drawSpeedChart() {
    let avgData;
    this.getAvgData()
        .then((avgDataResponse) => {
            console.log(avgDataResponse);                
            avgData = avgDataResponse;
            return this.getCarNames();
        }).then((carNames) => {
            console.log(carNames)
            this.createChart(carNames, avgData)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error', err);
        })
}
```

Checkout [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzwyrgjo/) to see working example

Comment: Hi Pal! Thanks for the feedback!! The first "console.log(avgDataResponse)" still returns undefined. So the chart has been drawn without the y-axis values of avgData. Should be a problem with the 'getAvg()' function?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a JS Fiddle, where the code is working.